# Erro no algoritmo equação do segundo grau em java

Tags: java, equações

Bom dia, alguém poderia me ajudar a entender porque o meu código não está fazendo o processamento correto e porque meu desvio condicional está errado?

```
public void cap4ex3e(){
    double a,b,c,delta,x1,x2;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = in.nextFloat();
    b = in.nextFloat();
    c = in.nextFloat();
    if ((a!=0)&&(b!=0)&&(c!=0)){
        delta = Math.sqrt(b)-4*a*c;
        if (delta<0) {
            System.out.println("Não há solução real");
        } else if (delta>0){
            x1=(-b+Math.pow(delta,1/2))/(2*a);
            x2=(-b-Math.pow(delta,1/2))/(2*a);
            System.out.println("Há duas soluções reais: "+x1+"e"+x2);
        } else {
            x1=(-b+Math.pow(delta,1/2))/(2*a);
            x2=(-b-Math.pow(delta,1/2))/(2*a);
            System.out.println("Há apenas uma solução real: "+x1+"e"+x2);
        }
         System.out.println("Não é uma equação do 2º grau");
    }
}
```

Quando eu atribuo os valores positivos para as variáveis a, b e c ele cai no desvio condicional

```
if (delta<0) {
    System.out.println("Não há solução real");
```

e:

```
System.out.println("Não é uma equação do 2º grau");
```

O que não era pra acontecer.

Acredito que seja o saída num lugar errado da condição mais não estou conseguindo ver isso.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O cálculo do delta está errado, ele deve ser

> [image: delta - bhaskara]

atualmente está como

> [image: delta errado - bhaskara]

Note que a última mensagem

> Não é uma equação do 2º grau

está sendo mostrada sempre, imagino que falte alguma validação de quando deve mostrá-la ou não.

E também que na parte em que só há uma solução real, a solução é impressa duas vezes.

Eu fiz alguns ajustes no código, pra deixá-lo mais legível. De forma geral, o erro é apenas na fórmula que calcula o delta.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a, b, c;
        try {
            a = in.nextDouble();
            b = in.nextDouble();
            c = in.nextDouble();
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) {
            System.out.println("A, B e C precisam ser diferentes de zero");
            return;
        }

        double delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
        double x1, x2;

        if (delta < 0) {
            System.out.println("Não há solução real");
        } else if (delta > 0){
            x1 = (-b + Math.pow(delta, 1/2)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.pow(delta, 1/2)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Há duas soluções reais: " + x1 + " e " + x2);
        } else {
            x1 = (-b + Math.pow(delta, 1/2)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.pow(delta, 1/2)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Há apenas uma solução real: " + x1 + " e " + x2);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/FlippantUsedHashfunction)

Comment: Para ser uma equação de segundo grau, não seria apenas o A que deve ser diferente de zero?

Comment: @Articuno Sim. Só na equação completa que todo mundo tem que ser diferente de zero. Mas isso é uma validação do código original, eu só troquei a ordem.

Comment: @Articuno, com certeza. Também observei que na parte em que só há uma solução real está sendo impresso dois números: a raiz e ela de novo

Comment: Isso. O código tá certamente incompleto

Comment: "Há apenas uma solução real: x1 e x2" Wait, pensava que tinha uma só

Comment: Mas no exercício do livro que estou estudando, ele pede para fazer uma equação do segundo grau completa.

Comment: @LINQ, muito obrigado pela explicação e mostrar onde estava o erro no processamento, agora vou consertar as saídas que também estão errada, mas minha duvida mesmo era o porque o programa não estava fazendo o processamento do delta e porque estava saindo sempre a ultima saída dizendo que não  era uma equação do 2º grau.